# Can importlib import more than one module at a time in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-importlib

I need to import two modules (determined at runtime) in the same package and I was wondering if it could be done with one `import_module` command.

Basically, I want the equivalent of

```
from some_package import module1, module2
```

Ways I could do it:

- Call `import_module` once for each module
- Have `__init__.py` import the two modules, then import the package
- Use `__import__`, but this doesn't use `importlib` and is discouraged by the docs.

There are probably more ways to do it than this. Can it be done with a single call to `import_module`? Failing that, is there a way to do this that is considered the standard way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One call? Probably not. You can however do:

```
for module in modules:
    importlib.import_module(module)
```

or:

```
 map(importlib.import_module, module)
```

Why does it matter if it's more than one call? The internal implementation of all the ways to import is probably serial and individual 'calls' either way.